# Tie specific functions to options-update for limiting API requests

Tags: plugin-development, api, options

I'm coding an update for my Mollie payment gateway plugin for WordPress (for Easy Digital Downloads). The old plugin only performs one API call to the Payment Gateway, when processing a payment. The customer is then redirected to the Mollie gateway payment screen where they can choose a payment method.

In the new version I want to load the payment methods dynamically into Easy Digital Downloads, so the customer can select the desired payment method in the checkout page. I have this part working, but the plugin now makes three API calls every time the page loads, which is highly inefficient. 
The functions calling the API are
process_payment()
get_payment_methods() and
get_payment_method_icons()

I want to store the output of the last two functions in my plugin options. This info doesn't change very often, so the only time it would need to update is when an admin updates the plugin options. If you would activate a new payment method in the Mollie dashboard you would also need to select it in the EDD options.

I'm looking for an approach to fire off the get_payment_methods() and get_payment_method_icons() functions only when the plugin options are updated.

Comment: Does the plugin have a hook for when settings are saved? Simply use this to make your API calls and save the results using the options api. You might also consider using transients (caching) https://codex.wordpress.org/Transients_API

Comment: I checked the plugin code and it does have a settings_updated hook. I'll try that one out and see how it works out.